# Please explain the equation $f(x_0+te_m)-f(x_0)=\frac{1}{2!}{t}^{2}(m+o(1))$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Definition 1** The set $S(a;r)=\{x\in{\mathbb{R}}^{m}|d(a,x)=r\},r>0$, is called the sphere of radius $r$ with center $a\in{}{\mathbb{R}}^{m}$.

From Vladimir A. Zorich, Mathematical Analysis I, pp. 464-465:

**Theorem 6** Let $f:U(x_0)\to{}\mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^{(2)}(U(x_0);\mathbb{R})$ defined in a
neighborhood $U(x_0)\subset{}{\mathbb{R}}^{m}$ of the point $x_0=(x_0^1,\dotsc,x_0^m)\in{}{\mathbb{R}}^{m}$, and let
$x_0$ be a critical point of the function $f$. If, in the Taylor expansion of the function at the point $x_0$
$$
\begin{align}
&f(x_0^1+h^1,\dotsc,x_0^m+h^m)=\\
&\quad=f(x_0^1,\dotsc,x_0^m)+\frac{1}{2!}\sum_{i,j=1}^{m}\frac{{\partial}^2f(x_0)}{{\partial}x^i{\partial}x^j}h^{i}h^{j}+o(\|h\|^{2}) \tag{8.67}
\end{align}
$$
the quadratic form
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j=1}^{m}\frac{{\partial}^2f(x_0)}{{\partial}x^i{\partial}x^j}h^{i}h^{j}\equiv{\partial}_{ij}f(x_0)h^{i}h^{j}\tag{8.68}
\end{align}
$$
a) is positive-definite or negative-definite, then the point $x_0$ has a local extremum at $x_0$, which is a strict local minimum if the quadratic form (8.68) is positive-definite and a strict local maximum if it is negative-definite;

b) assumes both positive and negative values, then the function does not have an
extremum at $x_0$.

*Proof* Let $h\neq{}0$ and $x_0+h\in{}U(x_0)$. Let us represent (8.67) in the form
$$
\begin{align}
f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)=\frac{1}{2!}{\|h\|}^{2}\left[\sum_{i,j=1}^{m}\frac{{\partial}^2f(x_0)}{{\partial}x^i{\partial}x^j}\frac{h^{i}}{{\|h\|}}\frac{h^{j}}{{\|h\|}}+o(1)\right] \tag{8.69}
\end{align}
$$
where $o(1)$ is infinitesimal as $h\to{}0$.

It is clear from (8.69) that the sign of the difference $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)$ is completely determined by the sign of the quantity in brackets. We now undertake to study this quantity.

The vector $e=(h^{1}/{\|h\|},\dotsc,h^{m}/{\|h\|})$ obviously has norm 1. The quadratic form
(8.68) is continuous as a function $h\in{}{\mathbb{R}^m}$, and therefore its restriction to the unit sphere
$S(0;1)=\{x\in{}{\mathbb{R}}^m\,|\,\|x\|=1\}$ is also continuous on $S(0;1)$. But the sphere $S$ is a closed bounded subset in ${\mathbb{R}}^m$ , that is, it is compact. Consequently, the form (8.68) has both a minimum point and a maximum point on $S$, at which it assumes respectively the values $m$ and $M$.

If the form (8.68) is positive-definite, then $0<m\leq{}M$, and there is a number $\delta>0$ such that $|o(1)|<m$ for $\|h\|<\delta$. Then for $\|h\|<\delta$ the bracket on the right-hand side of (8.69) is positive, and consequently $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)>0$ for $0<\|h\|<\delta$. Thus, in this case the point $x_0$ is a strict local minimum of the function. One can verify similarly that when the form (8.68) is negative-definite, the function has a strict local maximum at the point $x_0$. Thus a) is now proved.

We now prove b). Let $e_m$ and $e_M$ be points of the unit sphere at which the form (8.68) assumes the
values $m$ and $M$ respectively, and let $m<0<M$.
Setting $h=te_m$, where $t$ is a sufficiently small positive number (so small that $x_0+te_m\in{}U(x_0)$), we find by (8.69) that
$$
\begin{align}
f(x_0+te_m)-f(x_0)=\frac{1}{2!}{t}^{2}(m+o(1)) \tag{8.70}
\end{align}
$$
where $o(1)\to{}0$ as $t\to{}0$.

Please explain Eq. (8.70), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got the point:

Let 
$$g(h)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{m}\frac{{\partial}^2f(x_0)}{{\partial}x^i{\partial}x^j}h^{i}h^{j},$$ 
$g(h)$ is continuous as a function $h\in{}{\mathbb{R}^m}$, and $g(e_m)=m$. Setting $h=te_m$, We have $\|h\|=t$ and  $g(te_m)=t^2m$, since $g(h)$ is a quadratic form. So that
\begin{align}
f(x_0+te_m)-f(x_0)
&=\frac{1}{2!}{\|h\|}^{2}\left[\sum_{i,j=1}^{m}\frac{{\partial}^2f(x_0)}{{\partial}x^i{\partial}x^j}\frac{h^{i}}{{\|h\|}}\frac{h^{j}}{{\|h\|}}+o(1)\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{2!}{t}^{2}\left[g(te_m)\cdot{}\frac{1}{t}\cdot{}\frac{1}{t}+o(1)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2!}{t}^{2}\left[t^{2}m\cdot{}\frac{1}{t^2}+o(1)\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{2!}{t}^{2}\left(m+o(1)\right)
\end{align}

Is it correct?